How to properly start configuring Stratix II FPGA using microprocessor?
I'm trying to configure Altera FPGA using microprocessor in passive serial mode. According to Stratix II Device Handbook, I'm expecting that when I drive nConfig low, Config Done signal should be driven low by FPGA. However, none of the signals react to this action. I never get past this part of my code:
MFBSP2_FPGA.GPIO_DR.bits.NCONFIG = 0;
while (MFBSP2_FPGA.GPIO_DR.bits.CONF_DONE == 1) {
    asm volatile("nop");
}

I've also tried to first drive nConfig high for a while before driving it low: still nothing.
MSEL is 100% set to PS.
To start configuration I take these steps(minimal):

Set ports of my MFBSP for I/O: nConfig O, Config Done I
Wait PORSEL(100 ms)
Drive nConfig high for 1 ms
Drive nConfig low untill Config Done is low

Am I missing something obvious here?
